# Change the default GCS location for DAGs for Cloud Composer

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-cloud-composer, terraform-provider-gcp

Is there a way to override the default path for Airflow DAGs. While creating a new environment and executing one, the composer environment is creating a multi-regional bucket in the project.

Are there ways to override the DAG location to another GCS location and also change the storage class to regional? I have found the `core-dags_folder` is the property used to specify the DAG location on the environment, but I do not understand why this is a blocked configuration and cannot be updated to any other GCS location by the developer

Answer (score 2):

At the time, no, the default path for Airflow DAGs in Cloud Composer cannot be changed.

This is likely by design (which is why `core-dags_folder` is a blocked configuration value), because one or more managed components (like the Airflow web server) depends on these paths to coordinate DAG sync/etc. If you're curious, you can read more about the data synchronization [here](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/concepts/cloud-storage#data_synchronization).

If you have a strong use case for a single-region storage class or an alternate DAG location, I would recommend [filing feedback](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/getting-support#file_bugs_or_feature_requests).